# Convert All PODs from the given namespace into one big HTML page

Tags: perl

Several times need consult the docs. Some (bigger) systems consists from many packages and pods, and not always is clear where is the given method described, e.g. it is in `Pgk::Req` or in `Pkg::Utils` etc...
It is really time consuming and terribly boring searching the right POD for the description of the given method. ;(

Therefore looking for some way how to convert all POD's from the given namespace, e.g. `Some::Pkg::` into one big HTML-page.

I don't need any fancy cross-linking or such - just one big formatted html page where i quickly can find the description of the wanted method. I don't care of the page size - just want get *one* easy-to-read page.

I tried browse many POD-like modules in the Metacpan - but found no module what can do the above. In short, something like:

```
make_bigpod CHI::* >one_big.html
# and will get ALL docs for CHI.pm and CHI/*.{pm,pod} into one big page
```

Any suggestion how?

Answer (score 1):

The maintainer of the perldoc page is Jon Allen.  He has a Perldoc Server you can use to create a webpage like the perldoc site, but using your code and pod.  It includes a search area as well as syntax highlighting and indexes.

http://search.cpan.org/~jonallen/Perldoc-Server-0.10/lib/Perldoc/Server.pm

You could probably merge the generated html into one document if you really want to...

Another option (TIMTOWTDI) would be to write a short script to iterate over your .pm files, collecting the package names and pod sections (use the perldoc parser http://search.cpan.org/dist/Pod-Perldoc/), and just roll your own custom html from the results.

Answer (score 1):

If you want only one big html page without crosslinks and nice formatting just use the [Pod::HTML](https://metacpan.org/pod/Pod::Html) core module. If comes with the `pod2html` command, so it is possible to do something like:

```
cat $(find ~/path/to/packages -type f -print | grep -E 'NameSpace.*\.(pm|pod)') | pod2html --quiet > all.html
```

In the `all.html` will be the documentation for all modules from the `NameSpace`. Dirty, but usable and quick.

Answer (score -1):

Not to be flippant but why not just use perldoc from the command line or use search.cpan.org?

perldoc man page: http://perldoc.perl.org/perldoc.html

Comment: As far as I know, `perldoc` doesn't provide a way to view the documentation for multiple modules at once, and neither does search.cpan.org. (Also, the OP never said their modules are on CPAN.)

Comment: Imagine. I know, than _somewhere_ in the `Pkg::*` (> 40 packages) exists some method what does something with `JSON`. I don't know the method exact name. Now, `perldoc-ing` 40+ pods from a command line and trying to find "somewhere" the string _json_, is terrible. Really would be (at least for me) easier to get one big html-page and the simple "find" in the page, would give the result.